# Does nodejs requires bind class method?

Tags: node.js

I am using `node 12` in my project. Back to 2 years ago, I remember I need to bind method for class instance method like below:

```
class Logger {
  constructor () {
    this.printName = this.printName.bind(this);
  }

  printName (name = 'there') {
    this.print(`Hello ${name}`);
  }

  print (text) {
    console.log(text); 
  }
}
```

But recently I found I don't need to call `bind` in the constructor. Does the latest node version support auto-bind already?

Comment: Behavior hasn't changed. You only need to bind if `printName` is being called as a callback itself, like `.then(myLogger.printName)`

Comment: Could you be more specific about `bind if printName is being called as a callback itself`? How should I do that? The code works fine event without the `binding`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior hasn't changed. The situation in which you need to `.bind` is when the instance's `printName` method would otherwise get called without a calling context. For example:

```js
class Logger {
  printName (name = 'there') {
    this.print(`Hello ${name}`);
  }
  print (text) {
    console.log(text); 
  }
}
const l = new Logger();
const fn = l.printName;
fn();
```

or with, instead of `fn`:

```
setTimeout(l.printName)
```

or with:

```
button.addEventListener('click', l.printName)`
```

In all of these situations, an error will be thrown if you don't use `.bind`, because the method gets called without a calling context - but the calling context of the `Logger` instance is needed for `this` to refer to the instance, so that `this.print` refers to the `print` method of the instance.

This sort of thing has always been true in Javascript. Nothing's changed in the past few years, except that it's now a bit easier to bind - you can use new class field syntax instead of having a constructor:

```js
class Logger {
  printName = (name = 'there') => {
    this.print(`Hello ${name}`);
  }
  print (text) {
    console.log(text); 
  }
}
const l = new Logger();
const fn = l.printName;
fn();
```